# Span showing end of text, but hiding start

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have some text that can be edited when someone clicks on it. The `span` is then replaced with an `input` and when someone hits enter it goes back to being a span. All is well and good and it works nicely.

I am running into an issue when the text overflows however. The input is 350px wide and when the user enters a lot of text, you only see the end of the text input. That's good. But when you then hit enter and the span is shown again, you only see the end of the text. If I refresh the page I see the start of the text with an ellipsis overflow as expected.

I have no idea why this happens. Any ideas or thoughts about how to go about fixing?

I am using React.

The code in question:
https://gist.github.com/elie222/cd86b4a8b41f5ca022fa046d716a7527

```
import * as React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div<{ light?: boolean }>`
  display: inline-block;
  /* when using inline-block and overflow: hidden the text rises unless using v align bottom */
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: ${props => (props.light ? 'var(--black)' : '#fff')};
`

const Title = styled.span`
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* makes things look weird on small screen */
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
`

const TitleEdit = styled.input`
  font-family: Exo;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--light-grey-blue);
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 350px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  ::placeholder {
    color: var(--light-grey-blue);
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  }
`

export interface EditableTitleProps {
  title?: string
  updateTitle: (title: string) => void
  readOnly: boolean
  containerClass?: string
  placeholder?: string
  light?: boolean
  preText?: string
}

interface State {
  editting: boolean
}

export default class EditableTitle extends React.Component<EditableTitleProps, State> {
  state = {
    editting: false,
  }

  titleEdit: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.createRef()

  private updateTitle() {
    if (this.state.editting) {
      this.props.updateTitle(this.titleEdit.current!.value)
      this.toggleEditting()
    }
  }

  private onKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.charCode === 13) this.updateTitle()
  }

  private onBlur = () => this.updateTitle()

  private toggleEditting = () => {
    if (this.props.readOnly) return

    this.setState((state: State) => ({
      editting: !state.editting,
    }))
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <Container className={this.props.containerClass} light={this.props.light}>
        <div>
          {this.props.preText && <span>{this.props.preText}: </span>}
          {this.state.editting ? (
            <TitleEdit
              ref={this.titleEdit}
              placeholder={this.props.title}
              onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              defaultValue={this.props.title}
              autoFocus
            />
          ) : (
            <Title onClick={this.toggleEditting}>{this.props.title}</Title>
          )}
        </div>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Parent containers may also be affecting the final HTML/CSS ouput however.

Here are some images of the different behaviour

Input selected with cursor at the end:

[image: Input selected with cursor at the end]

**Problematic span element not showing start of text:**

[image: Span view]

Input selected with cursor at the beginning:

[image: Input selected with cursor at the beginning]

Span view after moving cursor to the beginning of input:

[image: Span view after moving cursor to the beginning of input]

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: You have `white-space: nowrap;`, fixed width, and `overflow: hidden;`. Should you really have all that if you don't want to hide the text?

Comment: I do want to hide the text. That's fine. But when in non-edit mode, I'd like it to show the start of the sentence. Not the end. (I added some images to hopefully make this more clear)

Comment: I suppose the width of the container is limited because of max-width: 280px and the span in the container is limited to this length too.

Comment: Could it be that, when you show again the span, the cursor is positioned at then end of the span, thus it shows the end of the text? You may wanna try to move the cursor at the beginning of the text when you show again the span

Comment: Yeah. That's basically what is happening. But how does the span have a cursor? The span is not scrollable.

A potential solution may be for me to move the cursor to the start of the input just before it gets removed from the DOM.